# How to redirect using PHP and unset any existing get parameters

Tags: php, html, redirect, get

*How can I redirect back to my starting page with PHP to clear my GET parameters?* I have made a form that once filled out will be sent to a .php file that handles the GET data and saves it to a database. After that I am using header("Location: redirect.php") which then again redirects to ("Location: main.php"). After these are both executed I get sent back to something that looks like the main page but instead I get the url formSaver.php?alot=ofparamters when I get back. If I click something I will get into the main.php part and it works. But if someone hits F5 before they click anything I will get double entries. Anyone know what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
header( "Location: http://www.your-site.com/" );
die;
```

Comment: Still got the get parameters in the url, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: After hard location change, there is no way you can have parameters in url, unless you are redirecting with them, meaning `"Location: http://www.your-site.com/?etc=1"`

Comment: header("Location: http://www.mydomain.com/myfile.php"); Still get it back with all the parameters, must be some sort of crash between the different languages or something I figure

Comment: Did you add `die;` after redirect?

Comment: yeah, I even had a middle page that did only session_start, header redirect (Again) and die (again). O_o Just have to stick to it then :/

Comment: What's in your session? Could it be that session creates you new data? Try `print_r ( $_GET );` right at the top of the page you are redirecting to. If you get no data, then the data is generated later on.

Comment: My session only stores userid and usermail for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

`header( "Location: your-previous-page" );`

In your Previus page:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET)) {unset($_GET);} ?>
```

Comment: Seems like it should work but I still get all the $_GET parameters in the url. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to hardcode the current host or path:

```php
$uriParts = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 2);
header("Location:" . $uriParts[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think $_GET method is available all the time.
you can just clear those parameters by

```
unset($_GET);
```

Whether you should check by isset operation. Like;

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['logout'])){ 
      session_destroy();
      header("Location: Your page ");
   }
```